# Distributed Shared Secret for RNG that only Distributor knows?

Tags: server, client, secret-sharing, custom-scheme

For one of my projects I want to create a way to sync up all participants' RNG with a seed where each participant does not know the seed of the RNG but also in a way that minimizes the number of times that the central distributor that knows the shared secret must be involved. Is there such a scheme to accomplish this task?